# How to await multiple functions?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have a program which connects to something, fetches object references (two types) and each reference can be used to search through large nested dictionary to get details. My program is as of below -

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
def get_connection(URL):
    
    '''This connects to the URL and gives a connection object'''
    username = "abc"
    password = "xyz"
    connection = Connect(URL, username, password)
    return connection

async def get_object_ref(connection, type: list) -> dict:

    '''This returns all the object references for a specific connection type'''
    objects = set()
    container = connection.CreateView(connection.root, type)

    for object_ref in container.view:
        objects.add(object_ref)

    return objects

async get_OPTION1_details(x: str) -> dict:
    
    '''Returns a dictionary which is created by searching a large nested dictionary'''
    result = {}
    x['Name'] = x.name
    x['salary'] = x.salary
    x['address'] = x.home_address['home']['address']
    x['hike'] = x.salary['hike']

    return result

async get_OPTION2_details(x: str) -> dict:

    '''Returns a dictionary which is created by searching a large nested dictionary'''
    result = {}
    x['Name'] = x.name
    x['parent'] = x.parent
    x['address'] = x.home_address['home']['address']
    x['date_of_joining'] = x.details['employee']['employment_details']['date']['date_of_joining']

    return result

async def main():

    URL = 'acbd.xyx.ad.com'
    types = [[OPTION1], [OPTION2]]
    connection = get_connection(URL) # Received connection to pass through and get results for OPTION1 & OPTION2 asynchronously

    # Creating lists for appending the tasks, one each for fetching objects, for OPTION1 details, for OPTION2 details
    object_tasks, OPTION1_tasks, OPTION2_tasks = [], [], []

    for type in types:

        task = asyncio.ensure_future(get_object_ref, type)
        object_tasks.append(task)

    # To fetch object references asynchronously for the two types
    all_object_references = await asyncio.gather(*object_tasks)


    # Now, the idea is to fetch OPTION1 details asynchronously for all the object references received in the above line of code
    for option1_object in all_object_references[0]:

        task = asyncio.ensure_future(get_OPTION1_details, option1_object)
        OPTION1_tasks.append(task)

    OPTION1_result = await asyncio.gather(*OPTION1_tasks)

    # Now, the idea is to fetch OPTION2 details asynchronously for all the object references received in the above line of code
    for option2_object in all_object_references[1]:

        task = asyncio.ensure_future(get_OPTION2_details, option2_object)
        OPTION2_tasks.append(task)

    OPTION2_result = await asyncio.gather(*OPTION2_tasks)

    print(OPTION1_result)
    print(OPTION2_result)


asnycio.run(main())
```

The problem I am facing is that though the "get_object_ref" is running asynchronously, the other two functions aren't running.
Tried using ThreadPoolExecutor as  "threads.map(func, list_of_values)" but the threads are getting locked and it's arduously slow.

**Note:** The URL mentioned above isn't a web URL so aiohttp doesn't work in this case.

How to best implement this asynchronously ? What is the mistake that I've made ?

Comment: Your `get_OPTIONx_details` functions are not asynchronous at all.  They are totally synchronous routines that accept an input and produce one output from that input.  Totally linear code.  There is no opportunity for multitasking there.  Plus, they aren't going to take any time, so there's no point in trying.  Now, you might be able to construct a pipeline here, where each pipeline is itself linear, but multiple pipelines run in parallel.

Comment: Remember that `async` is not like multithreading.  An `async` function hogs the CPU until it reaches an `await`.  You don't have any `await`, so those functions are going to run linearly.

Comment: Using await on the returnable dictionary doesn't allow me to use. Neither I'm able to await anything inside the function. However if I run it synchronously, due to the amount of data it has to search through, it's quite slow. Close to 3 minutes for 400 objects.

Comment: Yes, but that's because you have 3 minutes worth of processing to do.  In Python, neither async/await nor multithreading is any help at all with CPU-bound code.  It ONLY helps with I/O-bound code.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any other approach that I can look into or take advantage of apart from async/await, or threading ?

Comment: Because of the global interpreter lock, 3 minutes of computation in Python always takes 3 minutes.  You can overlap I/O calls, like connecting to the URL and fetching the document, but beyond that that are no easy ways.  It's possible to use multiprocessing (NOT multithreading), but if this is 3 minutes once a day, who cares?